# How to install actual JDK on Synology

Tags: server, synology

How can i install a actual jdk on my Synology DS213 air,

I have installed IPKG,JAMVM and JIKE that i can start a RMI-Server on my NAS but when i start the java I get this error:

```
DiskStation> jikes -cp /opt/lib/rt.jar RunRmiRegistry.java
Found 1 semantic error compiling "RunRmiRegistry.java":
    42.                                 for (String string : list) {
                                                                 ^
Semantic Error: Enhanced for loops (also known as foreach loops) are only supported for `-source 1.5' or greater.
```

On my PC i have installes jdk 8.45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Synology DS213 Air can not be get a newer Java then Java 5 so its not impossible to install the actual Java